# Pass parameter to custom post type single while keeping clean url

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I'm working on passing a get parameter to a single custom post type in a clean url. So for instance there would be the custom post type 'services' which would have the single post 'gardening'.

```
/services/gardening/leeds
```

which would translate to the following so the variable is accessible on the template:

```
/services/gardening?location=leeds
```

but still show as the following in the browser:

```
/services/gardening/leeds
```

I just wondered if anyone had done that before using custom post types?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can add this parameter in URL with this code to put after registering the custom post type :

```
add_rewrite_tag('%location%', "([^&]+)");


$slug =      get_post_type_object("services")->rewrite["slug"];
$query_var = get_post_type_object("services")->query_var;

add_rewrite_rule(
      "$slug/([^&]+)/([^&]+)$"
    , "index.php?$query_var=\$matches[1]&location=\$matches[2]"
    , "top"
);
```

after adding this in your plugin, you need to flush rewrite rules once :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

then you can read the location with `get_query_var("location")`. the magic of wordpress is that this code works with URL `/services/gardening?location=leeds` and `/services/gardening` too.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Kaperto! Would that work for /services/gardening/leeds or perhaps /services/gardening/location/leeds as well? I've tried it after flushing the rewrite URLs but it seems to redirect to the contact page rather than a 404 page