# Subpages URLs for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, advanced-custom-fields

I have a CPT named "especialidades", so right now the page have URLs likes this ones:
webpage.com/especialidades/some-name

webpage.com/especialidades/other-name

The template for this CPT shows tabs, in each tab is visible a block of HTML from a field created with Advanced Custom Fields.

I need to add URLs for each tab. Examples:

webpage.com/especialidades/some-name/tab1

webpage.com/especialidades/some-name/other-tab

So when you enter in this URLs the tab of the URL is the one selected on the page.

Please advice (and sorry for my english)!

Edit:
I need the URLs to be indexable by search engines so using something like #tab-name doesnt work for me

Comment: Please share the template that creates the tabs. That will be important in determining whether it is even possible to navigate directly to a page with a particular tab open.

Comment: look this to add a parameter in URL : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352189/pass-parameter-to-custom-post-type-single-while-keeping-clean-url/352215#352215

Comment: What @WebElaine said. :) Also, if you are open to it, consider using the ID of each tab in the URL instead, so for instance webpage.com/especialidades/other-name/#tab1, webpage.com/especialidades/other-name/#tab2. Here is a tutorial on how to do that with the repeater field of ACF: https://acfextras.com/create-tabaccordion-style-content-with-acf-repeater-and-responsive-tabs/

Comment: @WebElaine is a simple HTML/JS tabs structure and I can edit this to fit with the solution for the URL's problem

Comment: @Michelle I need different URLs so this can be indexed by search engines. Using #tab-name don't solve my problem

Comment: If you don't share the code, we're only guessing what you will need to do. Michelle's suggestion is the right one. Either you have tabs, which means all of the contents of all of the tabs is available on a single page but you can ensure a particular tab loads using an anchor (hashtag) link - or, you have separate pages, meaning you don't have tabs - perhaps you would use a menu that looks like tabs instead. If you have say 4 tabs, search engines are not going to index 4 different URLs that have the same content repeated verbatim, they're only going to index one.

Comment: @WebElaine exactly!! that's the problem
Currently I have a page with tabs (all the content of the tabs is in the same page).
I need to make this work in different URLs for each tab, maintaining the appearance of the tabs to simulate this.
Is like having several pages for a single post. Each page shows one of the HTML fields containing the tab code.
That is why I do not share the code. The current page is no longer useful for what I need. I must modify it.

Comment: How about adding a WP nav menu and just styling it differently than the top navigation? That way it can look like tabs but actually navigate to separate URLs.

Comment: @WebElaine my client have already a lot of content in this custom post type and dont want to change his way of editing content. So I can change templates and anything but the "format" of the post type and his fields :(

Comment: Adding a styled WP nav menu only requires editing the template for that post type. No changes are needed for the editor etc.