# How to allow URL with filename & extension in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, pages, database, urls, htaccess

How to create custom URL routes?

I wanted to generate csv using specific url for ex. https://www.example.com/exportcsv.csv

Is this possible via WordPress?

I have tried with querystring and all the otherways but my requirement is to do it with the above URL.

Comment: look here to see a example of new route with URL rewriting : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352189/pass-parameter-to-custom-post-type-single-while-keeping-clean-url/352215#352215

Comment: @Kaperto Are you able to create answer for the same please?