# WordPress URL redirect and replace ? question mark

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

Following is example of what we are looking for.
We're trying this in wordpress and we require all parameters as a variable

---

Example 1 : http://example.com/tno/?parent=abc

Need this : http://example.com/tno/abc

---

Example 2 : http://example.com/tno/?parent=abc&sub1=abc&sub2=abc

Need this : http://example.com/tno/abc/abc/abc

---

**funtion.php** code OR **.htaccess** rule any suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: to customise URL look that : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352189/pass-parameter-to-custom-post-type-single-while-keeping-clean-url/352215#352215

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Please show us your code.

Comment: function archive_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=client&parent=$matches[2]&sub1=$matches[3]&sub2=$matches[4]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'archive_rewrite_rules');

http://example.com/tno/?parent=helloenergy&sub1=zelf-aan-de-slag&sub2=mentaal

http://example.com/tno/helloenergy/zelf-aan-de-slag/mentaal

Comment: @VipulGhetiya Please [edit] your question, and add that code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Into wordpress function file add following code and check it.

```
add_filter('query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'parent'; 
    return $vars;
});

function archive_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^(.*)/(.*)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=client&name=$matches[1]&parent=$matches[2]',
    'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^(.*)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=client&name=$matches[1]',
    'top'
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules(); // use only once
}

add_action( 'init', 'archive_rewrite_rules' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, go to Dashboard Setting > Permalink and change to "Post name" link type or you can use a plugin like [enter link description here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/)
And for redirect you can use this plugin: [enter link description here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/)