# Rewrite rules automatically for pages using specific template

Tags: url-rewriting, page-template, rewrite-rules

I'm using rewrite rules to add an optional parameter to a page. This page uses a specific page template which handles the implementation of an external data source.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^page/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=page&id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

When the page is loaded, the template loads an index from the external source or, if an id is given, a specific object.

Since I'm developing a theme and don't content manage the website, I'd like to add the rewrite rule based on the page name the template is used on. The slug could also be changed by editors down the line, that's why I want to somewhat automate this.

I know that rewrite rules are added (and flushed) best after theme activation, so I'm wondering if there is a different approach I could take to achieve this.

**Edit**
It doesn't seem to be clear what I'm trying.
I want that a page template enables a page to have a virtual path component.
If the page link is `/page` I want to be able to open `/page/1513` or `/page/test` and get `1513` or `test` as query parameter.

Comment: if customisation concerns data, it's more plugin development and not theme development. edit your question to give more details about the functionality you need.

Comment: I added some info, but I think the regexes show it pretty well. This is included in the theme because it is a page template. And I'm writing a theme for a customer, so I don't see a point in moving the logic to a plugin. It would be more complicated to do it with a plugin and in the end, alls APIs are available to both, plugins and themes.

Comment: may be this can help you ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352189/pass-parameter-to-custom-post-type-single-while-keeping-clean-url/352215#352215

Comment: This would actually work. But as far as I know you're not supposed to add rewrite rules on each page load. Am I wrong with that?

Comment: you can and you must add this `add_rewrite_rule` on each page load [but you flush the rules cache only after modifications](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)